# Add doughnut and pie label

Tags: chart.js

I would like to create a pie chart with label within each set. I tried chartjs-plugin-datalabels plugin. But, the label shows value instead of label. Is it possible to update its configuration to show label? Thanks

Comment: Add some code..

Comment: try using [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/)